# Running macro through button causing US date format

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code I run each morning that converts transactional data into a table then creates a Pivot Table based off of that data.

I have a button in a separate spreadsheet that I use to run these macros, but when I use the button the code formats the dates in US format not UK.

```
Sub TUFRFormat()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Columns("A:Y").Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit 'Ensures data is displayed correctly
    Columns("B:B").Select 'Rearanges columns to be presented correctly
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Columns("Z:Z")
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("F:F,G:G,H:H,I:I,J:J,U:U,V:V,W:W,X:X").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hides unrelevant columns
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$Y$50000"), , xlYes).Name _
    = "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9" 'Selects a table theme
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Unit]]").Select
    ChDir "P:\Desktop\Prior Day Journals\Tueday - Friday"

' Creates a pivot table based off of the sheet 'Data'
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Table" 'Adds new sheet and names it table
    Sheets("Table").Select
    Sheets("Table").Move Before:=Sheets(1) 'Moves to the first sheet in the document
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Table1", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _
    :="Table!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Table").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Posted")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Year")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Period")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Unit")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum Amount3"), "Count of Sum Amount3", xlCount

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RowAxisLayout xlOutlineRow

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Posted").CurrentPage = _
    "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Posted")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Posted"). _
    EnableMultiplePageItems = True
```

I have tried looking for an obvious answer, but when I run the code directly rather than through the button it formats the dates as the UK format.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try using `Range("Range with the date").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"`. I know it shows like it was US date on the code, but it works somehow.

Comment: Sorry my brain is still getting into gear this morning, would this be an addition to the code or editing the range for the table?

Comment: An addition to the code. I think before the `' Creates a pivot table based off of the sheet 'Data'` comment line. I didn't post as an answer because I don't use that in a long time

Comment: At the moment it doesn't want to run that line for some reason, but it looks like that will be a solution. Thank you

Comment: Try making some tweaks to it. An alternative is also to use `Cdate()` to convert the information to date.

Comment: Will do, I wasn't expecting someone to just do it for me (learn better that way), but at least I have a starting point. Thank you